# How to get intersection in Entity Fraemwork if relationship between tables many-to-many?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

I have this model ( the model is more, but now it is not important)

[image]

I have some annotations and I would like to get all users how work with these annotations, but I get this exception("Unable to create a constant value of type 'DataBase.Annotation'.
 Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."), when use next code

```
TextCorporaEntities TextCorporaContext = new TextCorporaEntities();
List<DataBase.Annotation> annotations = //annotations which I used  
//I get the exception here
var UserAnnotationsResult = TextCorporaContext.Annotation_User.
        Where(x => annotations.
            Contains(x.Annotation));
```

I can use this code, but it is not productive

```
List<Annotation_User> listResult = new List<Annotation_User>(); 
foreach (var x in annotations)
{
    listResult.Concat(TextCorporaContext.Annotation_User.Where(y=>y.AnnotationId == x.Id));
}
```

How to get all users who used some annotations ?
How to get all users who used some annotations where AccessType equals ReadOrWrite(in model it is saved in string) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Contains only with primitives

I think this should work

```
var annotationsIds = annotations.Select(a => a.AnnotationId)
var UserAnnotationsResult = TextCorporaContext.Annotation_User.
    Where(x => annotationsIds.
        Contains(x.Annotation.AnnotationId));
```